# How to deal with lots of data?

Tags: python

I need to deal with lots of data (such as float) in my program which costs me much memory. Also, I create some data structures to organize my data which cost memory, too.

Here is the example:

```
Heap at the end of the function Partition of a set of 6954910 objects. Total       size = 534417168 bytes.

Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
0 3446006  50 248112432  46 248112432  46 array.array
1 1722999  25 124055928  23 372168360  70 vertex.Vertex
2 574705   8 82894088   16 455062448  85 list
.......
```

Any solution?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: A common way to deal with this issue is to process the data incrementally as opposed to reading it all into memory at the same time.

Comment: @ChristophTerasa how to save memory

Comment: @martineau I have to load all data in memory at the same time

Comment: So your question is how to use less memory but load the same amount of data in the same format? Since you don't really specify where that data comes from and how it's processed nobody can answer that. Anyway, unless you hit some memory limitations during processing, what is the problem with using all the memory you have? That's what is actually its purpose.

Comment: @ChristophTerasa mainly I deal with float data which cost much memory.And I use some data structures to organize them which also cost much memory.So I want to find a way to save my rare memory

Comment: Do you have an example of how your data is stored and loaded? Your "example" is simply a pretty-print output of...something.

Answer (score 1):

Python supports `array` objects that are internally maintained in packed binary arrays of simple data.

For example

```
import array
a = array.array('f', 0. for x in range(100000))
```

will create an `array` object containing 100,000 floats and its size will be approximately just 400Kb (4 bytes per element).

Of course you can store only values of the specific type in an array object, not any Python value as you would do with regular `list` objects.

The `numpy` module extends over this concept and provides you many ways to quickly manipulate multidimensional data structures of this kind (including viewing part of arrays as arrays sharing the same memory, reshaping arrays, performing math and search operations and much more).

Comment: I need just one dimension meanwhile maybe I need to deal with 18,000,000 or more float.I use array now

Answer (score 0):

If you need to deal with billions of rows of data per day, by far the simplest way to do that is to create a simple indexer script that splits the billions of rows in to small files based on some key (e.g. the first two digits of the IP address in a log file row).

If you need to deal with things like numbers theory, or log files, or something else where you have a lot of ints or floats:

1) Learn to use Numpy arrays well

2) Start using Numba's just-in-time compiling

3) Learn Cython (you can do much more than with Numba)

At least moderate level linux skills is a huge plus in dealing with large sets of data. Some things take seconds to do directly from command line, while it might not be at all obvious how to do the same thing in python.

At the very least use %timeit to test range of scales leading to your desired scale (e.g. 2,5 billion rows per day). This is a easy way to identify possible performance drops, and reduce size of arrays or other factors accordingly.

Learn more about profiling / performance hacking as soon as you're doing something with data.

To make the point about 'indexer' clear, a very simple example indexer I've created and used for doing a lot of computation on files with billions of rows of data using a $60 per month server.

https://github.com/mikkokotila/indexer